# Rails: Method for joining if a user has liked a set of songs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

- User
- Playlist
- SongLike
- Song
- ...

When I query a playlist for all of its songs, I get an array of song objects returned. What's the most efficient way to find out which of these songs a user has "liked"? The likes are stored in the SongLike model:

```
class SongLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :song, :counter_cache => "likes_count"
end
```

...this is the song model:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
  has_many :featured_songs
  has_many :song_likes
  has_many :users, :through => :song_likes
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize your song_likes association along with the songs in memory rather than querying the db multiple times:

```
# user.rb
def songs_liked_from(subset)
  like_ids = self.song_likes.where(:song_id => subset.map(&:id)).select(:song_id).map(&:song_id)
  subset.select{|s| liked_ids.include?(s.id) }
end
```

Comment: To make the `like_ids.include?` call a little more efficient you could also minimize the size of `like_ids` by doing this: `like_ids = self.song_likes.where(:song_id => subset.map(&:id)).select(:song_id).map(&:song_id)`. This would impact performance if a user had hundreds of likes, some of which were outside of the subset.

Comment: A user might have many thousands of likes, could you update the answer with the optimization? Is it usable if a user might have 2000+ likes? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You could put an index on user_id and song_id being looked up together and maybe make it unique if that works for your system.

```
  def songs_user_liked
    user_liked_songs = []
    songs.each do |song|
      song_like = SongLike.find_by_user_id_and_song_id(#,song)
      if song_like.song_like_count > 0
        user_liked_songs << song
      end
    end
    user_liked_songs
  end
```